# Login to Docusign API through apex

Tags: salesforce, apex, docusignapi

I am trying to connect to Docusign REST API making 'login_information' call from the Salesforce developers console, but having an issue:
'The URL provided does not resolve to a resource'.

Here is my code:

```
private static final string TOKEN_URL = 'https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information';
private static final string userName = 'username';
private static final string password = 'password';
private static final string integrationKey = 'integrationKey';

string authenticationHeader = 
                '<DocuSignCredentials>' + 
                    '<Username>' + userName+ '</Username>' +
                    '<Password>' + password + '</Password>' + 
                    '<IntegratorKey>' + integrationKey  + '</IntegratorKey>' + 
                '</DocuSignCredentials>';           


HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
Http http = new Http();        

req.setEndpoint(TOKEN_URL);
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
req.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
req.setHeader('X-DocuSign-Authentication', authenticationHeader);
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setBody('');

res = http.send(req);
```

I am able to log in to Docusign Console using my credentials, so all is correct. But can't do the same through Apex. Could it be lack of permissions?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the URL above.  I'm not an apex guru so not sure if there's something going on with your SF permissions or access.  Are you able to make calls to any other external services?  And what type of SF account are you using, a developer sandbox or production account?

Comment: Also, not sure if it's related but one issue I see is that you are setting the content type to JSON but providing an XML formatted auth header.  You should use the JSON formatted auth header instead.  See halfway down this page for what that looks like:  https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/quick-start/first-api-call

Comment: Ergin,
It seems no matter what format I put - XML or JSON, the result is the same - 404 error.
I am working in sandbox and I used to work with Zuora API with no problem.

Problem fixed!
this: req.setBody(''); should be removed from code.

Comment: Glad you figured this out!  Can you answer your own question for the benefit of the community?  If not I can post it... Thx

Comment: I need to wait till tomorrow to answer. Will do it. Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 1):

req.setBody(''); should be removed from code. It fixed the problem.